# libgdx make android back button act like home button

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want the back button of an android device to act like the home button when pressed (pause the app and lose focus)

i have this :

(`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);` and `Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);` are called)

```
@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if(keycode == Input.Keys.BACK) {
        pause();
    }
    return false;
}
```

but calling the `pause()` method isn't enough, what can i call to make it act like the home button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true); // This will prevent the app from being paused.
```

Use [Interfacing](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) and call platform specific code by core module

Inside core module

```
interface PlatformService{

    fun moveToStack()
}
```

Implement above interface in Android module

```
@Override
public void moveToStack() {
    this.moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Get reference of your implementation in core module and call implemented method on keyDown back button

```
 Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter(){
        @Override
        public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

            if (keycode==Input.Keys.BACK){
                 platformService.moveToStack();
            }

            return super.keyDown(keycode);
        }
    });
```

Comment: "get reference of your implementation" can you be more precise ?

Comment: @JackNeth sure I’ll try to add some details when I reach home

Answer (score 0):

call `YourActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);` instead of `pause();` method
like:

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Add above code in activity where you want to act back button like home button.

Comment: what class needs to be implemented to have this method ?

Comment: i'm not showing anything, the back button is next to the home button in android

Comment: moveTaskToBack work on android apps, i want this but in libgdx

Comment: The LibGDX wiki documentation explains how to call Android code.